# rstudio code folding like in matlab GUI

Tags: r, matlab, rstudio

I normally use matlab GUI for programming and it has very nice code folding features, such as the following:

```
    %% This is one chunk of code I can fold just because I am using the %% comment format.
    matrix = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
    vector = [1 2];
    ax = vector*matrix;

    %% This is another chunk of code I can fold because I am using the %% comment format.
    matrix2 = [7 8 9; 10 11 12];
    vector2 = [7 8];
    ax2 = vector2*matrix2;
```

As mentioned in the matlab code, the %% comment will  immediatly give the matlab GUI the folding option and a plus/minus sign for unfolding/folding will appear on that line with the comment visible.

Is it anyway to achieve such formatting in rstudio or a good R gui?

I'd like to have the plus/minus feature, and the fact that the first line comment is visible so I can know what's in the folded chunk of code.

Thanks.

Photos of the GUI minus/plus unfolded/folded attached bellow:

[image: minus folding]
[image: plus folding]

When I try the same approach in RStudio, seems that the only option is edit -> folding collapse/expand but it hides the comments, and its not as automatable as the %% feature.  In my case is more of a problem because I use X11 so I do not want to have to go to edit -> folding... all the time, but rather automate as in matlab using %%.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you seen the [code folding](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/code_folding) section of the RStudio documentation? Everything you ask for is described therein.

To directly quote the most relevant section of the documentation, you can create a code section on any comment line by `including at least four trailing dashes (-), equal signs (=), or pound signs (#) automatically creates a code section.`

If that wasn't clear enough, maybe we can learn by example:

```
 # Section One ---------------------------------

 # Section Two =================================

 ### Section Three #############################
```

To illustrate that this actually works further, please examine the following two screenshots. If you are getting something different, I suggest you update RStudio and then follow up directly with the good folks at RStudio:

Expanded:
[image]

Collapsed:[image]

Comment: yes but it does not seem to behave the same way as matlab does, I haven't been able to see a plus/minus or show the comments.

Comment: @Dnaiel - re: your first question - RStudio seems to use arrows to denote whether the code chunk is expanded or collapsed. The comments on the first line are visible regardless on my version of RStudio. Re: your second question, if you take 3 minutes to read the documentation, I think you'll see that it is very well thought out, logical, and directly answers your questions. I see no point whatsoever in duplicating the efforts of others when they answer your question...since the Internet is a big place, it's entirely possible you hadn't come across that yet...sorry to offend your sensibilities.

Comment: @Dnaiel You were quite abrasive in your response and I was quite put off by how you were treating Chase.  On a more related topic note that you need to have at least 4 trailing characters for the folding section to be created. (ie `# Section 1 ####` would work but `# Section 1 ###` wouldn't create a folding section)

Comment: @Dnaiel - see my updated answer. Your specific question seems to be 1) use four trailing `-`, `#`, or `=` to denote a code section. 2) Instead of a plus and minus sign, code sections are denoted by a right or down arrow. 3) Comments are visible on the top line regardless of whether the code section is expanded or not...if you don't have this behavior - upgrade your version of RStudio or log a support ticket with them. 4) Be less angry, people do this for free.

Comment: @chase Thanks Chase, and sorry about jumping out with such a negative and unhelpful attack.  The confusion was because I got negative points and thought chase was being not trying to answer the Q but rather being ironic, it's my completely fault and I sincerely apologize to both, Dason and Chase.